# Second ring tone for my Google Voice phone number

Tags: ringtone, google-voice

I'm considering adding a second phone number to my android phone by using Google Voice. Can I have a different ring tone to indicate that a call is coming from that second number and not from my first number?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think to do this would be to set up Call Screening and Caller ID like so:

[image]

Then set up a contact for your Google Voice number with a custom ringtone.